# Mimicking Casting with Visual Studio's JavaScript IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I am passing in a jQuery object into a function from another file via an array like the following:

```
$(document).bind("loadStoreDisplayCallGoals", function(source, urlParams)
{
    var selectedStoreDocument = urlParams["storeDocument"];
}
```

`selectedStoreDocument` should be a jQuery object, however Visual Studio Intellisense will never recognize it as such. I tried adding extending `selectedStoreDocument` with `$.extend`:

```
// cast selectedStoreDocument to a jQuery type
$.extend(selectedStoreDocument, $);
```

However, extending `selectedStoreDocument` wiped out all of my jQuery methods (`.each`, `.find`, etc.).

How can I get `selectedStoreDocument` to appear as a jQuery object in IntelliSense? Note that I am working in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a separate file for utility functions, and a second file for the utility functions + VSDoc.

utilities.js:

```
function castToJQuery(item)
{
    return item;
}
```

utilities-vsdoc.js:

```
function castToJQuery(item)
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     1: $(item) - "Casts" the specified item to a jQuery object for the sake of Intellisense
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns type="jQuery" />
    return $("dummy");
}
```

Now I can call castToJQuery in any of my downstream files to make Visual Studio think a dynamic property is a jQuery object.

```
var selectedStoreDocument = castToJQuery(urlParams["storeDocument"]);
selectedStoreDocument.find("products");
```

Visual Studio now works with Intellisense for my dynamic urlParams["storeDocument"].

Comment: Interesting approach. Can you post a screenshot of how it looks?

Comment: I'll try to add some screenshots later today

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get intellisense for dynamically added properties. You need to define them statically (in a vsdoc or js file):

```
$.selectedStoreDocument = function() {
     ///<summary>A Selected Store Document</summary>
};
```

Comment: So there's no way to "cast" something for intellisense?

Comment: Javascript is not compiled language, nor does VS has a language srvice provider that can evaluate the language and provide c# like intellisense for you.

Comment: @Pedar, you should try ReSharper 6, its javascript engine is considerably more robust than the stock VS facilities for purposes of intellisense (and refactoring, etc.)

Comment: No, I understand that. I just wasn't sure if there was a comment tag available for variables akin to ///<summary>A Selected Store Document</summary> that I could use to "cast" my variable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by cast. Here's a reference to available tags: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx. Are you looking for `param type`?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify documentation information for a variable like this:

```
$(document).bind("loadStoreDisplayCallGoals", function(source, urlParams)
{
    /// <var type="jQuery"/>
    var selectedStoreDocument = urlParams["storeDocument"];
    selectedStoreDocument._
}
```

For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh542722(VS.110).aspx